# Recursive Indexing failing / Bootstrapping parameter estimates

Tags: r, forecasting, statistics-bootstrap

I working with mortality forecasting and have performed a bootstrap to create 2.000 semiparametric replications of my data. I am using the `StMoMo`-package, where a bootstrap function is available for mortality data. After running the bootstrap-command, I get a variable with a value called "bootParameters", which is a list of the 2000 replications. Each replication contains a model with 3 parameters, whereas I want to make a histogram over one of the coefficients.

I use the following code:

```
# Creating 2000 semiparametric bootstrap samples
JA_lc_fitM_boot1 <- bootstrap(LCfit_JA_M, nBoot = 2000, type = "semiparametric")

# Creating the histogram over one of the parameters for value x = 30 (age)
JA_lc_fitM_boot1[["bootParameters"]][[1:2000]][["bx"]][[30]]
```

But I get the error message that

> Recursive indexing failing at level 3".

However, when I just look at the parameter value for a specific replication (so for example 2, instead of 1:2000), I get the wanted value. **Is there any way to show a histogram over the 2000 values of the parameter estimate?**

Thanks in advance!

Anders

Comment: `[[1:2000]]` is not legal, `[1:2000]` is.